# pd.DataFrame: adding values in specific locations

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have want to add few values to a large DataFrame. For example, my original DataFrame looks as the following:

```
   0      1      2      3      4      
A 0.10   0.2   1.2     2.0     31
B 0.51   2.0   1.5     4.0     52
C 0.21   3.5   1.1     21.0     1.0
D 0.13   4.3   1.2     1.2     0.1
```

I have want to add a single value in the first column for the 5th, 6th and 7th rows. For example, the following is the desired outcome:

```
   0      1      2      3      4      
A 0.10   0.2   1.2     2.0     31
B 0.51   2.0   1.5     4.0     52
C 0.21   3.5   1.1     21.0     1.0
D 0.13   4.3   1.2     1.2     0.1
N 1.87
K 2.15
O 52.1
```

I also want to specify the row name. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

#### `combine_first`

Create a `new` dataframe then:

```
new = pd.Series(dict(zip('NKO', [1.87, 2.15, 52.1]))).to_frame('0')
df.combine_first(new)

       0    1    2     3     4
A   0.10  0.2  1.2   2.0  31.0
B   0.51  2.0  1.5   4.0  52.0
C   0.21  3.5  1.1  21.0   1.0
D   0.13  4.3  1.2   1.2   0.1
K   2.15  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
N   1.87  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
O  52.10  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `reindex` and `fillna` on column `'0'`

```
df.reindex(list('ABCDNKO')).fillna({'0': {'N': 1.87, 'K': 2.15, 'O':5.21}})


Out[719]:
      0    1    2     3     4
A  0.10  0.2  1.2   2.0  31.0
B  0.51  2.0  1.5   4.0  52.0
C  0.21  3.5  1.1  21.0   1.0
D  0.13  4.3  1.2   1.2   0.1
N  1.87  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
K  2.15  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
O  5.21  NaN  NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Slightly more dynamic and if you split into two lines, elegant.  `d = dict(zip('KNO', [1.87, 2.15, 52.1])); df.reindex(df.index | d).fillna({'0': d})`

Comment: Hi, Do we not need to distinguish A from B, B from C and so forth?

Comment: Also, would this thing work if the row name has more than one letter?

Comment: @user7852656: it would work. `reindex` accepts list of labels to use for index or columns. Just put row names in the list and pass it to `reindex`

Comment: @user7852656: let's say your current index is `row1 row2 row3` and you want to add row `row4  row5`  to `df`.  You just do `df.reindex(['row1' 'row2' 'row3', 'row4', 'row5'])` or to make it more flexible  `df.reindex(df.index.union(['row4', 'row5']))`

Comment: @user7852656: I don't understand your first question: `Do we not need to distinguish A from B, B from C and so forth`. Could you elaborate it?